# Шейдер работает в эдиторе, но не работает в билде

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Проблема заключается в следующем - пиксельный шейдер, который отлично работает в эдиторе, не работает в билде.

Шейдер уменьшает глубину цвета и вызывается из скрипта, в котором он применяется к изображению рендера, попутно уменьшая его размер (т. е. создаётся эффект укрупнения пикселей). Этот скрипт в эдиторе работает, и выглядит так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в билде игры нет ни увеличения пикселей, ни изменения глубины цвета (т. е. не работает не только шейдер, но и весь скрипт):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более того, если я пытаюсь в юнити вручную, не из скрипта, создать материал с этим самым шейдером, то ненадолго перестаёт показывать монитор :) и windows уведомляет о том, что видео-драйвер переставал работать. Так происходит каждый раз когда я пытаюсь просмотреть этот материал в инспекторе.

```
Shader "Custom/ColorReduction" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Dim ("Color Scale", Int) = 0
        _Br ("Brightness", Float) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader {
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform int _Dim;
            uniform float _Br;

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata_base v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX (v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            half4 _Col;

            half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR {
                _Col = tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv);

                float step = 1.0 / _Dim;

                for(float i = step / 2; 1.0 - (step / 2); i += step) {
                    if(_Col.r < i - (_Br * step)) {
                        _Col.r = i - step / 2;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for(float i = step / 2; 1.0 - (step / 2); i += step) {
                    if(_Col.g < i - (_Br * step)) {
                        _Col.g = i - step / 2;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for(float i = step / 2; 1.0 - (step / 2); i += step) {
                    if(_Col.b < i - (_Br * step)) {
                        _Col.b = i - step / 2;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return _Col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Что делать? Подскажите. Заранее благодарен.

P.S. Кстати говоря, для проверки убрал из шейдера циклы, сделал просто _Col.r = 1.0. В итоге, в эдиторе всё как надо, материал с шейдером в юнити нормально создается. Но! в билде всё-равно не работает. Поэтому привожу ещё код скрипта:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace PixelShader
{
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [RequireComponent (typeof(Camera))]
    public class RetroPixel : MonoBehaviour {
        public bool enableNotices;
        public int pixelSize;
        public int bitDepthColor;
        [Range(-0.5f, 0.5f)]
        public float brightness;

        int horizontalResolution;
        int verticalResolution;
        int lastPixelSize;

        Material _material;
        Material material {
            get {
                _material = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/ColorReduction"));
                _material.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
                _material.SetInt("_Dim", bitDepthColor);
                _material.SetFloat("_Br", brightness);
                return _material;
            }
        }

        void Start () {
            if (!SystemInfo.supportsImageEffects) {
                enabled = false;
                return;
            }
        }

        public void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest) {
            horizontalResolution = Mathf.Clamp((int)(Screen.width / pixelSize), 1, 2048);
            verticalResolution = Mathf.Clamp((int)(Screen.height / pixelSize), 1, 2048);

            if (material != null) {
                RenderTexture scaled = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(horizontalResolution, verticalResolution);
                scaled.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

                Graphics.Blit(src, scaled/*, material*/);
                Graphics.Blit(scaled, dest, material);

                RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(scaled);
            }
            else {
                Graphics.Blit(src, dest);
            }

            if (enableNotices) {
                if (lastPixelSize != pixelSize) {
                    Debug.Log("Cur resolution: " + verticalResolution + "x" + horizontalResolution);
                    lastPixelSize = pixelSize;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в том что при `Build` шейдер `ColorReduction` не добавляется в сборку. Чтобы он туда попал можно попробовать сделать материал с данным шейдером и привязать его к какому либо объекту в сцене, либо добавить его в ресурсы, либо что надежнее в настройках  `Edit / Project Settings / Graphics` расширить список включаемых шейдеров `Always Included Shaders` и добавить туда принудительно в конец `ColorReduction`.
у меня после этого ваш код заработал. А так в скрипте не удается создать материал и скрипт постоянно бросает `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если билд на Андроид, то шейдер могли урезать.
2. Проверьте настройки графики при запуске билда, поставьте на Fantastic.
3. Так же советую добавить шейдер в `Edit/Project Settings/Graphics`